# Which method is more stable to be used forever?

Tags: php, cron

You have a script that contains this

```
<?php
while (true) {
    echo 'Test';
    sleep (60);
}
?>
```

and a script that contains

```
<?php
    echo 'Test';
?>
```

and you run the second one with cron every 60 seconds.

Which method is more stable to be used forever?

`stable` meaning requiring less resources, causing PHP or apache or ubuntu less likely to crash even if there are hundreds of similar scripts running at the same time.

Comment: Define `stable`

Comment: Cron is the normal way to run a script on a shecdule

Comment: PHP isn't designed to run forever. Cron is the better option imo.

Comment: If you run it with cron it will survive reboots.

Comment: For something this simple, you probably aren't going to run into memory issues with a long-running script, but cron is definitely a better option in the general case.

Comment: @Rushikumar See new content

Comment: What if it *does* stop for whatever reason? With cron it's a non-issue.

Comment: Cron, especially because you have cron log.